# Mallus Maccius No Longer a Fence

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I began a new character with patch 1.4.21.4

I completed the Thieves Guild story line, where Mallus Maccius pledges to me to be a fence for my services. I moved on and became the Guild Master.

Now I am on a side quest to get to "Return the lexicon to Avanchnzel". So I decided to dump some of my gear. But to my surprise, with Mallus there are no dialogue options for a transaction. He says I have developed the brewery by dumping the last of the Honning-Brew mead. But no options for selling.

Before this patch, another character that I played, I was able to fence/sell my stuff just fine with Mallus.

Now I can not.

So far I have been following G.SE on how to avoid known glitches altogether.

If other people have experienced this problem, does some one know how to avoid this glitch for Mallus Maccius?

**EDIT**

Neither is Niranye in Windhelm, who should be a fence once you complete the Thieves Guild quest line as well.

At this point I think it is one and only one mod that I have active. When I started this play through with the latest patch (no longer latest since 1.4.27 I think) I had never used a mod. Only subscribed to one on Steam "Dovahkiin Hideout" for the big house, more space etc.

Maybe this is why my usual fences might not be fences. But Golum-Ei still is a fence. Too confused at this point.

Anyone in the gaming community have any problems with this particular mod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mallus Maccius not being available as a fence is a known bug**.
According to [UESP](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Mallus_Maccius):

> Mallus Maccius may not have the option to sell merchandise after
>   completing *Dampened Spirits*, despite offering to provide fence
>   services to you. Instead, at odd hours of the day, he will respond as
>   if the player is disallowed from entering the building.
>   A possible fix
>   for this is entering the Meadery through the basement.

Of Niranye a similar bug is not registered on UESP.
It does state on [elderscrolls.fandom.com](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Summerset_Shadows_(Quest)), however, that the mission *Summerset Shadows* must have been completed (which is not a necessity for completing the main Thieves Guild questline), and that she mustn't have "fought" (turned hostile towards the player, I presume) in the process.

Since, according to its description, it only "adds a very large basement connecting all houses in the game", **it is unlikely that [Dovahkiin Hideout](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?l=english&id=7611) has influenced the fences in Skyrim**. Nothing about it is mentioned in [the mod](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/12553)'s [thread](https://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?showtopic=605434) on the nexus.